How to configure Apache Kafka File Sink Connector to write JSON data as pipe-separated string and rotate files hourly?
I'm working with Apache Kafka and need to configure the File Sink Connector to achieve the following:

Convert JSON data to pipe-separated strings: The Kafka topic contains messages in JSON format, and I need the connector to write these messages to a file in a pipe-separated format.

File rotation: The connector should rotate the files every hour.


I've explored the configuration options available like transforms, but I'm not sure how to accomplish these requirements. Here's what I need:

How do I specify the JSON to pipe-separated string conversion in the connector's configuration?
What configuration options should I use to enable file rotation every hour?
If a custom converter is needed for the JSON transformation, how should it be implemented and integrated with the connector?

Kafka Topics would like this
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4","key5":"value5","key6":"value6"}

Output should be as follows
value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6


Files should be rotated as below. file should be rotated every hour.
output.txt_yyyyMMddhh
Any guidance or example configurations would be greatly appreciated!
Sample configurations for file sink connector.
name=file-sink-connector
connector.class=FileStreamSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=my-topic
file=/path/output.txt


If you want to convert JSON to pipe-delimited data, you'll need to write a custom transform or Converter subclass to do this.

If a custom converter is needed for the JSON transformation, how should it be implemented and integrated with the connector

Requires Java code to be packaged
package com.stackoverflow.example;

import org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter;

public class CustomConverter implements Converter {
  // TODO: Implement
}

Then placed on the plugin.path directory of the Connect worker(s)
Then referenced as value.converter=com.stackoverflow.example.CustomConverter.
transforms would be similar with a different interface.

The built-in FileStreamSinkConnector does not support file rotation. The S3 Sink, for example, does, and you could use tools like minIO server to emulate a local s3 endpoint on your local filesystem
